# WCF Schema common elements always null

Tags: c#, xml, wcf, xsd

I am using xsd to generate the object available in the OperationContract. The address, city, state and zip elements of the XSD are common

```
<xs:element name="Address" nillable="true">
  <xs:simpleType>
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:maxLength value="50"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
</xs:element>
```

and used throughout the XML.

```
<xs:element ref="Address"  />
```

When I compile the schema the classes generate correctly using the common elements.
When I run the service the OperationContext contains the expected request from the client:

```
      <NameLast>Last</NameLast>
      <NameFirst>First</NameFirst>
      <Address xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">123 2nd St</Address>
      <City xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">Somewhere</City>
```

However the common elements have the **xmlns** attribute (shown above) and in the received object all common elements contain null values.

My reputation is not high enough to show screenshot, but all data NOT in common elements are passed correct. Such as NameLast = "Last", Address = Null.

I am new to using Schemas and would appreciate any direction. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe what you want is this, placed before your closing `</xs:schema>` tag:

```
<xs:simpleType name="AddressType">
  <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
    <xs:maxLength value="50"/>
  </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

and used throughout the schema:

```
<xs:element name="Address" type="AddressType"  />
```